Connect to MSSQL hosted on Windows 2008 R2 from Amazon Linux 2023 PHP 8.2
I can't do anything with legacy database, can't migrate or update, I have to read some data from it. Personally, I'd love to migrate, but I can't.
Is there any way to connect Laravel 11 on PHP 8.2 with any ODBC to that old server?
If yes, what I should install/use to do that?
I tried adding this connection to config:
'legacy_database' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('LEGACY_DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('LEGACY_DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('LEGACY_DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('LEGACY_DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('LEGACY_DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'options' => [
                PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8,
                'TrustServerCertificate' => true,
                'Encrypt' => false,
                'LoginTimeout' => 30,
                'TraceOn' => 1,
                'ReturnDatesAsStrings' => true,
            ],
        ],

With this result:
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000102:SSL routines::unsupported protocol]


Sounds like your instance isn't just end of life, it's also out of date. What does PRINT @@VERSION; return on the instance?

Print where? I can connect via 'Azure data studio'

On the instance, run the statement; what does it return?

Thanks for clarifying that:
Started executing query at Line 1
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)
Apr  2 2010 15:48:46
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)
Total execution time: 00:00:00.039

By adding this file:
[ec2-user@... www]$ cat openssl.cnf
openssl_conf = openssl_init
[openssl_init]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect
[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
Options = UnsafeLegacyRenegotiation
And running:
OPENSSL_CONF=/web/...../www/openssl.cnf php dumb.php
Connected successfully.
I was able to connect but not yet in Laravel, posting this for future explorers

Well I was right... You're missing about 15 years of updates on your instance; the instance has had a single bug or security fix installed, ever. Get it updated; that is the only solution here.

for sure, I can't wait to do that but I can't, it is not under my control :(
Still trying to make it work with laravel

You won't able to. That instance does not support TLS 1.2. Support for it was added in a security patch in 2016. Get the latest SP and security patches installed.

I appreciate your help!

@RustamAnvarov: it sounds like you have a partial solution that might be useful for others. Could you post that as an answer?
